# Globbing with brackets and variables in zsh

Tags: zsh

I wrote the following snippet to delete several subdirectories selectively from a common ancestor. It doesn't work, but I can't tell why.

```
for x in *; 
do rm -r "$x/foo/bar/{a*,b,c,d,g*}"; 
done
```

I get "no such file or directory" errors when I run it, even though I know that the folders exist.

Comment: In zsh, you don't need the quotes at all. You do need the quotes in other shells. Except that here, you can write `rm -r */foo/bar/{a*,b,c,d,g*}` (in zsh, make that `rm -r */foo/bar/{a*,b,c,d,g*}(N)`, where the `N` glob modifier indicates that you want to skip non-matching patterns rather than signal an error).

Comment: @Gilles, Not even if the path contains spaces?

Comment: @IulianOnofrei Indeed. In zsh (except if explicitly configured for closer sh compatibility), `$foo` expands to the value of `foo` unless that value is empty. It doesn't do splitting and globbing on the value like other shells in the sh family.

Comment: @Gilles, So you need quotes if `x` in the OP's example points at a directory with spaces in name, right?

Comment: @IulianOnofrei You do in other shells, because they do splitting and globbing on unquoted substitutions. But not in zsh, because it doesn't split or glob unless explicitly told to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Brackets won't expand inside double quotes. Try this:

```
for x in *; 
do rm -r "$x/foo/bar/"{a*,b,c,d,g*}; 
done
```